# How do I resize the phone's screenshot size without using an image resizer?

Tags: screenshots

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, running a [pre-rooted stock ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=40710278&postcount=1).

Using the <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> combo, I can take a screenshot that is 1080x1920 by default. Is there any setting where I could change this fixed size, without having to use a 3rd-party image app to resize it?

Comment: 1080x1920 will be the native resolution of your phone's screen. Are you trying to take a screenshot of only part of your screen (cropping?)? Or do you want the image resized/downsampled before its saved?

Comment: @GAThrawn I want a full-screen screenshot, but in a smaller resolution. Although it's small in filesize, I want it smaller so that it doesn't look too big on a PC, or on email.

Comment: The closest solution I've seen is streaming the framebuffer to the PC but I can't get the new `adb shell exec-out` to work for some reason.